# Xamarin Android - Mono.Linker.MarkException when calling a method from another project

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, linker, mono

I have a Xamarin application which also has a project reference to an adapted version of the https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor project.
This has previously worked fine when I've used the linker to do a release build, but as I've been gearing up for a second app release, I now get a linker exception:

```
    Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
   Error        Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void 
   Project.ViewModels.ApprovalViewModel/<<get_EditCommand>b__26_0>d::MoveNext()' in assembly: 'Project.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void 
  TEditor.Abstractions.ITEditor::set_PageTitle(System.String)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
    at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
    at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()    Project.Droid    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets    632
```

The setter in question is just a method where I set the property of the object:

```
 _editor.PageTitle = ApproveTitle;
```

I know that this can be avoided by setting Linking to None but that's not going to help the app in the long run and I want to use the linker.
Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: have you read the Linker docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker

Comment: Yes. This exception doesn't feature at all in the linker docs